# How do I show two different partials on every other pageview?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using the `cycle` Rails method - largely because I couldn't think of another way.

All I am doing, is in my controller declaring this:

```
@banner_cycle = [1,2]
```

And in my view, doing this:

```
<div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs text-center">
    <% @banner_cycle.each do |x| %>
        <%= cycle(render "shared/banner_728x90", render "shared/banner_970x250") %>
    <% end %>               
</div>
```

This is the error I am getting though:

```
SyntaxError at /posts/another-awesome-test
syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it's changed or I've forgotten `cycle` doesn't work across page views.  It only works for the current view/page-load.  If you really want to alternate page views you'll have to keep state somewhere on the server.  Or, if you're okay alternating per user you can track it in a session.  Say something like...

In your controller action:

```
session[:banner_cycle] = session[:banner_cycle].to_i + 1
```

The `.to_i` is to protect against nil.

In your view:

```
<div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs text-center">
    <% if session[:banner_cycle].even? %>
        <%= render "shared/banner_728x90" %>
    <% else %>
        <%= render "shared/banner_970x250" %>
    <% end %>               
</div>
```

I suppose an aggressive user could overflow the maximum integer value, but I'm not going to worry about that here.

Comment: What I want to happen is whenever a user logs in (or just visits without logging in), when they hit the page the first time, they see `banner A`, when they refresh or go to another page and come back it shows `banner B`. I just tried this approach and it always shows me `banner A`.

Comment: Where did you put the controller code?  Add logging to see if it is being called and what the value is.

Comment: Actually...no...you are right. I had to update the contents of my partial. So just so I understand, this basically just keeps incrementing the `banner_cycle` banner for the session until the session has expired?